# How does packagingoptions work with Android App Bundle

Tags: android, android-library, android-app-bundle

I am running into an issue when generating `.aab` file for my application. Within my application I am including a `.aar` file of a library that I have created to share some basic functionalities across multiple apps. When I try to generate the Android App Bundle for my application it fails with the following error.

```
 A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'root/AndroidManifest.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'AndroidManifest.xml'.
```

The `.apk` generation works fine however.

After googling a little, I found a solution that recommends adding following block to my app's `build.gradle` file.

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
```

This solution works, but I do not understand why this works. As per my understanding, `exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'` will exclude the AndroidManifest file from being included in the `.aab` file. If this is true, then why does the app still work fine without the AndroidManifest file?

I knew that this issue was due to the library that I was using since if I removed that library from my app, I was able to generate `.aab` successfully without having to add `exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'` in my app's gradle file.

So I tried moving `exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'` block from my app to my library, regenerated the `.aar` file and added this new `.aar` file to my application. After doing so, when I tried to generate `.aab` file it worked as too. So it seems like it doesn't matter where I add `exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'` (within the library or the app). Both produce the same result. This got me really confused and prompted me with quite a few questions.

1. What am I doing wrong in my library (.aar) that is causing the generation of `.aab` file to fail with `File 'root/AndroidManifest.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'AndroidManifest.xml'.`?
2. Why does adding `exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'` fix the issue? Shouldn't excluding the AndroidManifest file crash the App since it won't have a AndroidManifest?
3. Why does adding `exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'` in either the app or the library have the same effect?

I think my confusion might stem from some misunderstanding on how Android App Bundles work. But would really appreciate it if I can get answers to the above questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show how you depend on this .aar in your project?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing actually. Did you ever find an answer to this?